# How to get the creation date of an Azure Application Registration using Azure PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azureportal, service-principal

I'm trying to find out when an Application Registration was created using Azure PowerShell. 
The `Get-AzureAdApplication` cmdlet doesn't have a property to retrieve this information. The closest I can get to using that cmdlet is I can find out the StartDate of certificate or client secret of that app.

The Application Registration blade in the portal now has a pretty new design and I can easily see that information there.

[image]

However, I cannot see this information inside the app itself (on any of the sub categories within)

[image]

Is there anyways I can pull this information from PowerShell? CLI?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the directly relevant PowerShell and CLI Commands do not return this information by default. Here are what I thought of as relevant commands..

- PowerShell (`Get-AzADApplication`, `Get-AzureADApplication`)
- CLI (`az ad app list`, `az ad app show`)

Only programmatic option that I could find to get to create date/time related information is Microsoft Graph API (beta endpoint only)

[Get Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{id}
```

You could very quickly try this out from [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

**Please note**: This is only available with beta endpoint and not with the stable v1.0 endpoint. APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

On a side note, if you absolutely have to do it from PowerShell, one workaround could be to invoke the Microsoft Graph API from PowerShell.

Here is a blog from TechNet that explains the steps in detail - [Connecting to Microsoft Graph with a Native App using PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudlojik/2018/06/29/connecting-to-microsoft-graph-with-a-native-app-using-powershell/)

Answer (score 1):

Piping to 'Get-AzAdAppCredential' will give you the start/end time for Application Registration:

Get-AzADApplication|Get-AzADAppCredential